# What is the best way to uncover weeping holes?

Tags: repair, brick, mortar, weep-hole

We just bought a house where an old man lived for 27years.  When he built the place, I doubt that he had any idea that the voids in the brick were weeping holes.  I would like to fix them, but I'm not sure the best way to do it without hurting the bricks.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the Doctor and his Tardis.

Comment: If only...(sigh)

Comment: Have they been intentionally sealed with something? Or just clogged with trash mortar? Or something else? What exactly is wrong that you're trying to repair?

Comment: He has actually filled them in with mortar.  It's not the same mortar used when the place was built and it looks messy.  I would like to break it out so the weep hole are functional again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Plugging Chisel.

> A [plugging chisel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chisel) has a tapered edge
>   for cleaning out hardened mortar. The
>   chisel is held with one hand and
>   struck with a hammer. The direction of
>   the taper in the blade determines if
>   the chisel cuts deep or runs shallow
>   along the joint.

[image: Plugging Chisel]